# Is it possible to pass hints to database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-2

Using rails 2.3.4, is it possible to pass a hint to the database optimizer? I would like to be able to force the use of a particular index for testing purposes.

I have (legacy code, yes it smells) :

```
with_exclusive_scope {
  succeeded.average(:elapsed,
                    :conditions => ["date between ? and ? ", month_start, month_end],
                    :joins =>["LEFT OUTER JOIN update_phases proot on (updates.id=proot.update_id AND proot.phase_id=#{UpdatePhaseType.find_by_name("update").id} and proot.started_at between '#{month_start.to_s(:db)}' and '#{month_end.to_s(:db)}')",
                              "INNER JOIN profiles ON updates.profile_id = profiles.id and profiles.customer_instance_id=#{customer_instance.id}"],
                    :group =>'date', :order =>'date')
}
```

and would like to be able to tack on `force index for join(profile_date_state_activity)` to the end of the `FROM` clause.

Failing that, I need an `average_by_sql` method...

Comment: Do you mean passing the hint for a SELECT statement but still using the ActiveRecord query syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the :from attribute to modify the SQL statement that is generated. I'm not sure what your table name is here, so in the snippet below replace "table" with that table name.

```
with_exclusive_scope {
  succeeded.average(:elapsed,
                    :from => "table force index for join(profile_date_state_activity)",
                    :conditions => ["date between ? and ? ", month_start, month_end],
                    :joins =>["LEFT OUTER JOIN update_phases proot on
                    etc.
```

*FYI in my environment the SQL statement was generated correctly and ran successfully, returning expected data, but I don't have conclusive PROOF that the hint is actually being used.*